# Non-standard finite difference for a reaction diffusion system

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, laplacian, finite-differences, runge-kutta-methods

I want to discretize the following reaction diffusion system:

$\frac{\partial u(x,y,t)}{dt}=\nabla ^2u+ u(1-u)-\frac{uv}{u+\alpha v}$,

$\frac{\partial v(x,y,t)}{dt}=d\nabla ^2v+ \delta v\left(\beta-\frac{v}{u}\right)$.

$\alpha,\beta,\delta,d$ are positive parameters.

**Question 1:** The numerical integration of the above system are to be performed by (i) using non-standard finite difference scheme for the reaction part and (ii) five point explicit finite difference scheme for the diffusion part.

**Question 2:** It is also asked to use five point finite difference schemes for the diffusion part and the **fourth order Runge–Kutta method for the reaction part**?

**Answer of question 1:**
Please correct my **non-standard finite difference** scheme (discretization technique) given below:

$\frac{u^{n+1}_{i,j}-u^n_{i,j}}{\Delta t}=
\frac{u^{n}_{i+1,j}+u^n_{i-1,j}+u^n_{i,j+1}+u^n_{i,j-1}-4u^n_{i,j}}{h^2}+ \color{red}{u^n_{i,j}(1-u^{n+1}_{i,j})-\frac{u^n_{i,j}v^n_{i,j}}{u^n_{i,j}+\alpha v^n_{i,j}}}$,

$\frac{v^{n+1}_{i,j}-v^n_{i,j}}{\Delta t}=d\frac{v^{n}_{i+1,j}+v^n_{i-1,j}+v^n_{i,j+1}+v^n_{i,j-1}-4v^n_{i,j}}{h^2}+ \color{red}{\delta v^{n}_{i,j}\left(\beta-\frac{v^{n+1}_{i,j}}{u^{n}_{i,j}}\right)}$.

***Query:***  Please specially check the red part. Is there any other, better way to answer the question? Please correct, if there is any error.

**Answer of question 2:**
I have used the five point finite difference scheme for the diffusion part. I failed to write the **fourth order Runge–Kutta method for the reaction part**. Please modify the non-standard finite difference scheme for Question 2.

**I would like to request you to answer both the questions in details. Thanks a lot for your support. It is very essential for me to learn the technique of non-standard finite difference.**